# How do I find the x value of an undefined tangent function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, special-functions

Apologies in advance if the formatting for the equations isn't great (first time doing this), hopefully it worked correctly though.

**The problem:**

Given the function $f(x)=-2*\tan(1.7*x-8.8)-7.7$ find the x value which is (a) undefined and (b) a x value at which $f(x)=0$

I have already found the undefined value by calculating $1.7*x-8.8$=$\frac{(\pi)}{2}$ which gave me $6.1005$

To find an x value at which $f(x)=0$, I tried entering the equation as:

$0=-2*tan(1.7*(6.1005)-8.8)-7.7$

$\ln(0)=\ln(-2*tan(1.7*(6.1005)-8.8)-7.7)$

and carrying it through from there however my answer kept coming back as either false or undefined.
Can someone help me with this? Its probably really simple but I cant think of any other way aside from the natural log method

Comment: What is $\ln(0)$? Why taking logarithms? Also there are an inifnite number of $x$'s at which $f(x)$ is undefined. Is the exercise asking for one such value or all of them?

Answer (score 2):

You've done the first half. For $f(x) = 0  \implies -2\tan(1.7x - 8.8) = 7.7\implies \tan(1.7x-8.8) = -\dfrac{7.7}{2}=-3.85\implies 1.7x-8.8=\tan^{-1}(-3.85)\approx-1.32\implies x \approx\dfrac{8.8-1.32}{7.7}\approx 0.97$.

Comment: Thankyou this really helps. So you don't have to use the undefined answer to figure out the next bit (like the undefined thing doesn't affect the end result)? Sorry if this is annoying (really bad at maths) but to clarify, if the question was something like "find x if $f(x)=5$ given $f(x)=0.7\cos*(2.7x+9.2)+4.4$ (without any undefined issues) then how would you enter the $f(x)=5$ value into the main equation to figure it out?

Comment: Can you post this problem in a new post and I can answer your post there?

Comment: It says I can only post once every 40 minutes.. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Do you need the answer asap or you can wait for about half an hour to post another one?

Comment: Just reposted the question~

Comment: OK. I will get to it.