# How do I calculate these trigonometric equations?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

How do I calculate questions such as:

Consider $f(x)=0.8\cos(3.1x+9.2)+4.4$, determine a value of $x$ such that $f(x)=4.5$.

Does it differ if $\cos$ where to be replaced by $\sin$ or $\tan$?

Please help.

EDIT: Thankyou everyone for helping, I really appreciate it

Comment: You will have to introduce inverse trigonometric functions such as $\cos^{-1}$. If $\cos a =b$ then $\cos^{-1} b = a$.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. How would I write this out to be put into a calculator?

Comment: The same method works as in your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4391449/how-do-i-find-the-x-value-of-an-undefined-tangent-function). If you really understood the answer there, this one should not be a problem.

Comment: Sine is the same as it is just a phase shift of cosine: $\sin(\pi/2 - x) = \cos x$. Tan is different because the period of tan is $\pi$ radians. Also, tan is a one-to-one function in $(0, \pi)$ or similar intervals, so it is actually easier as there is only one possible inverse value.

Answer (score 2):

$$0.8 \cos(3.1x-9.2)+4.4=4.5$$
$$0.8 \cos(3.1x-9.2)=0.1$$
$$3.1x-9.2=\cos^{-1} (1/8)+2\pi n\quad (\text{$n$ is an integer})$$
$$x=\frac{\cos^{-1} (1/8)+2\pi n+9.2}{3.1}$$

Comment: Thankyou so much!!

Comment: By writing $3.1x-9.2=\cos^{-1}(1/8)$, you are assuming that $3.1x-9.2$ is in $[0,\pi]$. The question does not say this.

Comment: So if they have done it incorrectly how do I go about this then?

Comment: @SemenDemon Fixed.

Comment: Also, you've typed the equation wrong. It should be $3.1x + 9.2$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But since $cos$ is an even function, $-\cos^{-1}(1/8)+2k\pi$ ($k$ and integer) is also a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simple trigonometric functions can be solved by yourself(such as tan(x)=1) but for the example you mention the way to go about it would be plugging it into a calculator(if you are doing this for class).

Generally, I would advise searching this kind of thing up on Quora or Youtube rather than Stack Exchange.

Anyways, for your calculator there are a few different ways to go about it:

1. Algebra
   0.8(3.1+9.2)+4.4 =4.5

0.8(3.1+9.2) = 0.1

(3.1+9.2) = 1/8

arccos(cos(3.1x+9.2)) = arccos(1/8)

3.1x+9.2 = arccos(1/8)

x=[arccos(1/8)-9.2]/3.1

So the last step is the only thing you would plug into your calculator

2. If you happen to have a graphing calculator you can graph the function you have(f(x)-4.5) and see where the graph is valued to be zero. This way is probably not expected of you just yet though so don't worry too much about it.

And yes, sin and tan are different functions than cos so the answers would be different.

Again, I recommend finding videos on Youtube for questions like these because it often explains these kind of things better than we can here(and is often better for these grade school kind of problems). Khan Academy is a pretty solid resource too.

Comment: the fact that the question is a duplicate has no connection with the quality of an answer. Also, there is nothing that prevents asking here a question that has been asked and solved somewhere else (in maths, it would be difficult to ask purely original questions).

Comment: There could be good answers on Quora but one should be cautious on videos for gaining knowledge (see here for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVtCO84MDj8&ab_channel=Veritasium). If you are not careful on the source of explaination, you end up with an answer from someone that does not know that $\arccos(\cos(x))=x$ is false in general...

Comment: Respectfully, Veritasium is a pop-sci source(and has been under numerous factual controversies). HW-help geared channels such as PatrickJMT and NancyPi are accurate just as often as Quora(and even SE) answers.
And I was not claiming that the fact that the question is a duplicate makes the answers that are being brought up worse, but rather that because it has been asked before many people have taken the time to already give thoughtful answers and have gone through the process of finding the optimal way to teach the concept.

Comment: @Taladris Also, on a note less relevant to our discussion could you provide me with a link for the arccos(cos())=  thing? I'm not saying I disagree with it I've just always assumed that it was true and would like to learn more about this hole in my knowledge.

Comment: Veritasium has a PhD in Physical Education, and his work on Khan Academy is a result of an experiment he conducted. $\arccos$ is usually defined as the inverse function of the *restriction* of $\cos$ to $[0,\pi]$, therefore $\arccos(\cos(x))=x$ is true when one assumes that $x\in [0,\pi]$. It is false for other values, for example $\arccos(\cos(-\pi))=\pi$. Source: every Precalculus textbook or Wikipedia on inverse trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 0):

$$0.8 \cos(3.1x+9.2)+4.4=4.5$$
$$0.8 \cos(3.1x+9.2)=0.1$$
$$3.1x+9.2=\cos^{-1} (1/8)+2\pi n\quad$$

where $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Now here is a pretty important correction to the other answers. When we write $\cos^{-1} (1/8)$, we assume that arccos is not multivalued. It is a one-to-one function with domain $x \in [-1, 1]$.

Using the identity $\cos(x) = \cos(-x)$, we have that:

$$x=\frac{\cos^{-1} (1/8)+2\pi n-9.2}{3.1} \quad \text{and} \quad x = \frac{-\cos^{-1} (1/8)+2\pi n-9.2}{3.1}.$$